# Как реализовать корзину, покупок?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

Голову уже раз 5 сломал, как реализовать корзину в подобном коде?
App.js:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Container } from '@mui/material';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar/index';
import { Home } from'./pages/Home';
import { Login } from './pages/Login';
import { Registration } from './pages/Registration';
import { CreatePost } from './pages/CreatePost';
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <Container maxWidth="full">
        <Routes>
           <Route path='/' element={<Home />}/>
           <Route path='/login' element={<Login />}/>
           <Route path='/register' element={<Registration />}/>
           <Route path='/createpost' element={<CreatePost />}/>
        </Routes>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

Card2(этот файл выводится на Home, а от туда в app.js):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import TabContext from '@mui/lab/TabContext';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';


import { Post } from '../Products';
import styles from './Card2.module.scss';
import { fetchPosts } from '../../redux/slices/posts';

export const Card2 = () => {

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('1');

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { posts } = useSelector((state) => state.posts);

  const isPostsLoading = posts.status === 'loading';

  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchPosts());
  }, []);


  return (
    <>
    <TabContext value={value}>
        <Grid xs={8} className={styles.box}>
          {(isPostsLoading ? [...Array(5)] : posts.items).map((obj, index) =>
            isPostsLoading ? (
              <Post key={index} isLoading={true} />
            ) : (
              <Post
                id={obj._id}
                title={obj.title}
                imageUrl={obj.imageUrl ? `${'http://localhost:4444'}${obj.imageUrl}` : ''}
                price={obj.price}
              />
            ),
            
          )}
        </Grid>
      </TabContext>
    </>
  );
};
```

Products

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { BsPlusCircle } from "react-icons/bs";

import styles from './Products.module.scss';
import { PostSkeleton } from './Skeleton';

export const Post = ({
  title,
  imageUrl,
  price,
  children,
  isLoading,
}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  if (isLoading) {
    return <PostSkeleton />;
  }



  return (
    <div className={styles.back}>
      {imageUrl && (
        <img
          className={styles.image}
          src={imageUrl}
          alt={title}
        />
      )}
      <div className={styles.wrapper}>
      <div className={styles.title}>{title}</div>
        <div className={styles.price}>{price}</div>
        <BsPlusCircle className={styles.plus} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: А где тут корзина? Что должно происходить при нажатии на что?

Comment: @SwaD в этом и суть, как создать корзину, чтобы при клике <BsPlusCircle /> товар добавлялся в корзину?

Comment: У тебя же есть Redux. Создай хранилище cart = {[id_product]: count}. При клике на кнопку вызывай событие добавления товара в корзину, в хранилище cart(добавляем ключ: количество) и отдельно сделай страницу с листингом товаров в корзине. А на странице товара проверяй корзину по ключу и если товар совпал подставляй значение

Comment: @SwaD спасибо большое, в ближайшее время попробую это реализовать, всего доброго